# Is an Android device supposed to charge when debugging via USB?

Tags: android, debugging, permissions, usb, device

I was just thinking it can't be great for the battery memory if the device is always charging at about 90-100%.
 Couldn't find anything on Google.
 Does anybody know about this?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to charge.

Comment: You are sure? What if I'm on 50% battery and then charge fully to 100%? I thought you weren't supposed to do this with electronics.

Comment: Then I'm guessing you've charged your phone. How you charge it doesn't affect battery life. 100% will stay 100%. It will just charge slower over USB, as USB ports give .5A current, while AC chargers range from 0.5A-3A in my experience.

Comment: This is actually a good question imho, though it should probably be moved to http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RaghavSood, it is known that charging to 100% is a bad idea. A battery should be charged up to 80% for a longer life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perfectly fine, for older phones the batteries couldn't handle being charged constantly and being taken on and off all the time so this was a bad idea.

However, newer devices this doesn't matter as the battery is much better suited for this type of work. Plus android takes care of the battery, i.e. when it feels it may be getting a tad too warm it will stop charging (although the phone will still show as charging) to let it cool.

This is completely fine and safe